# Cant make my magic file work

Tags: macos, unix

I have a magic file 
magic_file

`0 byte \x2A WORKS`

I compile it like this

```
file -C -m ft_magic
```

then I try to use it like this

```
file -m ft_magic
```

or like this

```
file -m ft_magic.mgc
```

In either cases it returns an error ( usage error ).
The general idea is to find if there is "42" written into my files. I would like to search for a specific extension to on another line of the magic file.

My magic file is in the same directory

Comment: Surely you would need to use this to test it... `file -m ft_magic.mgc someFile`

Comment: thanks the command works but it still can't search inside the file to find whether it's written "42" or not

Comment: Ok it works I changed byte by string like that 0 string 42 WORKS. Do you know how I can search for the extension of a file inside my magic files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search for extension in magic files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901184/how-to-search-for-extension-in-magic-files)