# How to search for extension in magic files

Tags: file, unix

I know you can find the extension with

```
file *.myext
```

But I'm wondering if I can write into my magic file a line which for example return a success message on all the ".42" ex : myfile.42

imagine a folder with the following files

- test1.42
- test2.kk
- test3.42

what should be the content of my magic file in order to make a success only on test1.42 and test2.42

I tried that for the moment

```
>0xA2 string 42 success
```

Comment: Your question is not very well formulated. For me (or is it just me?) it\`s still unclear what you want to do.

Comment: The file(1) manpage clearly enumerates the 3 types of tests that it performs, and none has anything to do with filenames.  I don't know where you got the idea that this could work, because that's simply not what the tool does.

Comment: You don't need file magic to search for files by their extension. For this, you have simple `ls *.42` or `find . -type f -name "*.42"` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linux/unix doesn't care about filename extensions, magic numbers represents first bytes of file which are used to determine type of file.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901184/how-to-search-for-extension-in-magic-files#comment76794637_44901184) the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/file/file.1.en.html) of the [`file`](https://darwinsys.com/file/) command lists three sets of tests and indeed none of them is related to file extensions.

> filesystem tests, magic tests, and language tests

It might be interesting to note though and a possible source of confusion that a list of file extensions *can* be contained in magic file definitions using the `!:ext` syntax. To my understanding these are purely informative though and have no influence on the classification.

For example the [magic file](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/jpeg) of the JPEG image format lists the following file extensions.

```
!:ext jpeg/jpg/jpe/jfif
```

As of [release 5.23](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/ChangeLog) these can be printed by supplying the  `--extension` parameter.

```
$ /usr/bin/file --mime-type file.jpg
file.jpg: image/jpeg
$ /usr/bin/file --extension file.jpg
file.jpg: jpeg/jpg/jpe/jfif
```